# How is Google Calculator implemented?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, string, pattern-matching

When you search in Google "100F to C" how does it know to convert from Fahrenheit  to Celsius? Similarly, conversion from different currencies and simple calculation.

What is the data structure used, or is it simple pattern matching the strings?

Comment: have you tried stuff at wolfram alpha ? It has database for lot of things and you can ask almost any question (that returns exact number or similar). It also shows how it parse you question. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=night+fall+in+Piran

Comment: Agreed with ralu - WolframAlpha uses an amount of Natural Language Processing, which is much more interesting and covers a wider variety of cases (try asking it the population of Findland, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly **simple** pattern matching. Evaluating the mathematical expressions you can enter is not trivial. For example, [here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) an algorithm that evaluates a math expression. That's just the evaluation, there's probably a lot of code to detect if it's even valid.

For the currencies conversion and other units, that's simple pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple pattern matching

try
100 kmh in mph = no calculation
100 kph in mph = 62.1371192 mph

Comment: "100 km/h in mph" works though: km/h is the correct abbreviation

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that for mathematical expressions (e.g. 100 * (6 +3)) they use a parser as they are non-regular.

Comment: @DrJokepu: agreed, but there is the harder problem of recognizing it is a suitable expression for sending to the calculator prior to treating it as a search string. I'm guessing there's a pile of regexps and heuristics for that determination.

Comment: @gbn thats my point it just looks for a bunch of strings. Of course if km/h is correct then it should also require mi/h. You can't have too many alternatives in your lookup or you will try and eval everything as a calculation.